# Time of creation of key in redis

Tags: time, redis

Suppose  I do this in redis at `13:30 20 Feb 2020`,

```
> set foo "bar spam"
OK
```

I want to get time of creation of `foo`. Is there something like

```
> gettime foo
13:30 20 Feb 2020
```

?

Comment: A built in command to get the time of creation would be extremely useful for debugging...

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Redis doesn't store this information.

You could use a separate key:

```
MULTI
SET foo "bar spam"
SET foo:time "13:30 20 Feb 2020"
EXEC

GET foo:time
```

Answer (score 19):

There is another, similar option to solve this, for the use case when you need timer to detect expired value without deleting the value itself:

```
MULTI
SET foo "bar"
SET foo:alive 1 EX 30
EXEC
```

Here `30` - is a desired timeout. You can then determine whether value is still "alive" with:

```
EXISTS foo:alive
```

Answer (score 9):

I think it's possible if you know initial TTL;

you can do like this:

```
$init = 60; //initial time
$ttl = $redis->ttl("key"); //current ttl
$diff = $init - $ttl; //difference is the time passed after key was created
$creation = time() - $diff; //this is creation time in seconds since unix epoch
```

Comment: I think this is a good workaround to store the creation time in Redis, but if you don't want your key to expire make sure you set it to a very long expiration that it will never happen, like 30 years (946080000)