# Item Duration in Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to create a metric to measure the amount of time that an item has been in a cache using Elasticache. There does not seem to be any built in metric for this in Cloud Watch, and I have struggled to run a query in logs insights to obtain this information.

I have tried running a query in log insights to create this metric, but it requires matching of an ID and the query language used in AWS does not seem to support these types of conditional queries. So I am unsure of how to solve this problem

Comment: Do you have a TTL set on the key? Or are you manually deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

ElastiCache and Cloudwatch do not store this information. You could, however, use a separate key as described here:
[Time of creation of key in redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917331/time-of-creation-of-key-in-redis)